# Dry run for cloudformation update

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to run AWS cloudformation update in dry run mode? Cos I realised that the aws validate does not pick up all the errors and when you run the update new errors are being thrown.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way of "simulating" a deployment before actually deploying your template. But `change sets` could be used in this vain. Found some articles about it [here](https://medium.com/boltops/a-simple-introduction-to-cloudformation-part-4-change-sets-dry-run-mode-c14e41dfeab7) and [here](https://medium.com/boltops/aws-cloudformation-dry-run-with-lono-cfn-plan-2a1e0f80d13c)

Answer (score 3):

The closest you could get to this is running mock testing which will require a fair amount of configuration time; it also cannot 100% guarantee you won't encounter any errors.

[Moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) has an extensive library dedicated to mock running AWS infrastructure and would be worth checking out, with the core endpoints of cloudformation included.